# In what case would bi-directional BFS have the same asymptotic run time as a regular BFS?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, trees

I'm not quite sure when they would have the same asymptotic running time. Would it be if the graph was each node connected to one other node in a line? I know that for a bi-directional BFS to have a worse running time a star graph would work, but I'm not quite sure how they would have the same asymptotic running time or how to design a set of graphs that would cause this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is bi-directional BFS?

Comment: Are you referring to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search ?

Comment: Yes I am referring to the search in this wiki page. : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search

Comment: The answer might depend on how you measure the asymptotic time (i.e., as a function of what variables).  Do you know how you want to measure it?  In algorithms we usually measure it as a function of $|V|$ and $|E|$, but in AI sometimes one uses other parameters  (e.g., branching factor).